# How to write a AWK command to find difference and comparison

Tags: bash, awk

I am new to BASH, and i am trying to write a basic script to fulfill my below requirement but i am stuck and your help to understand is highly appreciated

Requirement:

I have a command which gives the output, from that i would need to take only the column with keyword "Executin" and find the difference of the start time with the system time, and display the whole row if the difference is more than 4 hours.

**OUTPUT:** (Separated by Space)

```
UNIQUE ID   FILENAME    TYPE    DATE    STATE   STATUS  STARTED ENDED
--------    -----------------   ----    --------    --------    ------  
0000k66w    ABCDEF  TBL 20180224    Executin    OK  20180224060128  
0000k678    GHIJKL  TBL 20180224    Ended OK    OK  20180227060202  20180228054016
0000k67a    MNOPQRS TBL 20180224    Executin    OK  20180224200000  
0000k67d    PBKPUXBIP1XD01G TBL 20180224    FAILED  OK  20180227150000  20180227150118
```

The script i tried to apply on the above output is

```
//mycommand | awk' {if ($5 == Executin) && if(( `date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'` - $7 ) gt 40000)} ; print ;}'
```

Getting an syntax error

Comment: Since your dates in the file are not seconds since epoch but in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS you will have to bring them into seconds format using `date +%s` and then do a difference, but this brings in timezone and DST complexity as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ "date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S" | getline d} {if($5=="Executin") if(d-$7>40000) print}'
```

`"date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S" | getline d;` : Date would get store in `d`. System calls are expensive and keeping it in `BEGIN` block would trigger this system call just once at the beginning of awk processing and thereby improving the performance.

`if(d-$7>40000) print` : If difference is `>40000` print the record.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your comment.
The output is not in a file, it is a run-time output of a command. the tool which we use has few in-house commands, through which the above output is derived, from that i would like to find difference and print only the rows which are greater than 4 hours.

Comment: @Maya: In that case simply remove the `| file`  at the end and pipe this command to your original command. I've updated the difference to 40000.

Comment: I tried but it prints all the line of the output instead of the Executin jobs which are greater than 40000

Comment: @Maya: Do you want to print just the `Executin jobs` rows >40000 i.e. discarding `Ended` , `failed` jobs rows ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I want to print only the rows where the State is Executin and the Started is greater than 40000

Comment: I have the above output now like the below, (the space separated fields are now changed to Pipe separate fields),  in this case, i am unable to address $5 and $7. is there any way to control this?
UniqueD  FILENAME           TYPE  ODATE    STATE     STATUS STARTED            ENDED
-------- ----------------- ----  -------- --------  ------ --------------     -----
0000bgqg|ABCDEF  |TBL  |20121126|NOTOK|NOTOK |20121126000532|              | Hold
0000bh2n|ghijkl   |TBL  |20121126|Executin|NOTOK |20121126000641|              | Hold

Comment: @Maya: by default awk uses space as the delimiter. To specify a different delimiter say `|` for your  input you can use `awk -F"[|]"` before your actual logic.